# How to frame data-mage-init in ajax

Tags: html, ajax, magento2

I need to append the content into particular div using ajax call.

```
<div class="col-md-12 pd0" data-mage-init='{"imageResponsive": {}}'>
```

How to frame the content into html in ajax call

Comment: Can you show your ajax call ?

Comment: ajax call return only true or false value ..if its return true ..i need to append the div with data-mage-init.

Comment: Let me know if the answer helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by

```
 $('.pd0').attr('data-mage-init', 'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif');
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/allaudeen/a1zsn8cg/8/)

Here is the same in [my personal website](https://sulthanallaudeen.com/mano.html). You can find it by inspecting elements in 
HTML.

[image]